# count correct / incorrect answers after every verification

Tags: moodle

In moodle is it is possible to count correct/incorrect answers in Immediate feedback Test and show them in the quiz navigation panel?

at the end of the test there is a summary which count the correct answers, but how to show this in the quiz navigation panel after every question is verified?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

The "quiz navigation panel" is a special fake block that is displayed as part of the quiz attempt page, it is not an addon or a plugin, it's part of Moodle's core. so, any solution for your question has to involve core changes. if you are willing to do so, you can either use mod/quiz internal questions status display mechanism:
https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/mod/quiz/attemptlib.php#L1580-L1597

mod/quiz marks with green all the questions that the student has submitted correct answer to. so you can use that mechanism to display the count yourself.

Pick up parts of the following code snipets:

- Loop through the questions (slots):
  https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/mod/quiz/attemptlib.php#L2114
- And count the correct answers:
  https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/mod/quiz/attemptlib.php#L2125

Make a new function from the above snipets or just add the above snipets after the following line:
https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/mod/quiz/renderer.php#L336

Hope it helps.